# Como excluir linha de um dataframe com base em uma lista em python?

Tags: condição, dataframe

Gostaria de saber como exclui linhas de um dataframe com base na iguldade dos valores de uma coluna e uma lista.
Por exemplo:

```
df: 
cod letra
101  a
202  b
303  c
404  d
505  e
```

`lista = list([202,505])`

O resultado que eu espero é:

```
df_saida:
cod letra
101  a
303  c
404  d
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer usando `.isin()`, desta forma:

```
df_saida = df.loc[~df['cod'].isin(lista)]
#output:
    cod letra
0   101 a
2   303 c
3   404 d
```

O `.isin()` aqui retorna uma lista booleana mostrando quais valores são encontrados na coluna **cod**

```
df['cod'].isin(lista)
#output:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
```

com o `~` invertemos essa seleção, para pegar os que não se encontram na lista

```
~df['cod'].isin(lista)
#output:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
```